# Updating page element with HTML using JQuery + JSON + Symfony

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1

I am trying to update a DOM element with HTML generated from a symfony partial. I am using Symfony 1.3.8

Here is the (simplified) Symfony/PHP part:

```
public function executeFoobar(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $results = $this->renderPartial('foo/bar');
   $this->getResponse()->setContentType('text/json');
   return $this->renderText(json_encode(array('data' => $results)));
}
```

Here is the (simplified) HTML/jQuery part

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<a id='foo' href='#'>Click foo</a>
<div id="sink"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#foo).click(function(){
       $.ajax( {
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/ajax-example'
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result){ $('#sink).val(result.data); }
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert('Error: ' + thrownError); }
       });
   });
});
</script>
</html>
```

When I submit the AJAX post, the html is generated server side, but I then get the error on the browser with the following message:

```
 Error: Invalid JSON: <table>
       <tr><!-- Rest of generated HTML follows .... -->
        {"data": GENERATED_HTML }
```

Where GENERATED_HTML is the HTML generated at the server side - i.e.:

```
 <table>
       <tr><!-- Rest of generated HTML follows .... -->
```

So it seems the HTML is being included twice or something. Has anyone come accross this before - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`renderPartial` echos the text to screen. You need to use `get_partial` from the `PartialHelper`

```
public function executeFoobar(sfWebRequest $request)
{
     $this->getContext()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');

     $results = get_partial('foo/bar');
     $this->getResponse()->setContentType('text/json');
     return $this->renderText(json_encode(array('data' => $results)));
}
```

It's either `loadHelpers` of `loadHelper` I can't remember off the top my head, sorry.

Comment: Now that you point it out.. Its so obvious as to make me want to hang my head in shame ;)

Comment: NP, I do my best to help out on the symfony questions posted on SO

Answer (score 1):

While xzyfer's answer works, you should try to avoid loading helpers inside actions. It breaks MVC. Helpers are view-level, actions are controller-level. You can get the same result using an action and a template.

**Action:**

```
public function executeFoobar(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->getResponse()->setContentType('text/json');
  $this->setLayout(false);
}
```

**Template (foobarSuccess.php):**

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('data' => get_partial('foo/bar')) ?>
```

Note: this assumes that PartialHelper is one of your global helpers. This is the case for most people, but if it's not the case for you, add a use_helper() call at the top of the template.

Comment: @Iyoshenka: Hmmm. Thanks, thats interesting. I have never really thought of doing things that way. I must admit that is closer to the MVC ideal than what I am currently doing. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter version of the xzyfer's answer:

```
public function executeFoobar(sfWebRequest $request) {
   $results = $this->getPartial('foo/bar');
   $this->getResponse()->setContentType('text/json');
   return $this->renderText(json_encode(array('data' => $results)));
}
```